# Why my label in ASP.NET Windows Form is ufo font when i upload project to production machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, encoding, character-encoding

I'm created project WDF(.NET WindowsForm) in my local machine it look good but when i tried to open project in production machine (Windows Server 2016 standard) and then click in frm and it show me like this

[image]

So, I'm copy all font in local machine and parse it to production machine and then restart one time and i get the same issue

my label using "microsoft sans serif".

```
   frm text property in design show ÃÒÂ§Ò¹ÇÑ¹¹Ñ´
```

Have any person have the same issue & solved it ? Please share. Thank you so much.

Comment: WDF does not exist and WinForms is not ASP.NET. It is totally unclear what parts of the .NET framework you are using.

Comment: I'm using .net framework 3.5

Comment: That does not help. Pick 1 from WinForms / WebForms (aspx) / WPF / Other-GUI